Why is huxtable not showing caption text in bookdown::html_document2?
When knitting the below RMarkdown document the caption texts for both the base R plot and the flextable output are shown. The caption text for the huxtable output is, however, not. Why is that and how can I fix this?
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

## versions
```{r}
packageVersion("huxtable") # 5.5.6
packageVersion("flextable") # 0.9.4
packageVersion("bookdown") # 0.34
packageVersion("knitr") # 1.42
```

## number one

```{r numberone, tab.cap = "My cool huxtable"}
huxtable::hux(head(iris))
```

## number two

```{r numbertwo, tab.cap = "My cool flextable"}
flextable::flextable(head(iris))
```

## number three

```{r numberthree, fig.cap = "My cool figure"}
plot(1)
```


I think this is because huxtable outputs raw TeX or HTML, whereas flextable outputs markdown. Maybe set the caption by hand with huxtable::hux(head(iris)) set_caption("My caption").

Based on MGP's comment above this is a possible solution:
---
output: bookdown::html_document2
---

## number one

```{r numberone, tab.cap = "My cool huxtable"}
caption <- knitr::opts_current$get("tab.cap")
huxtable::hux(head(iris)) |>
  huxtable::set_caption(caption)
```

